# How to auto format code when type semicolon in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, format

I want type semicolon and then auto format code look like Visual studio.

Look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7abU.png)

don't this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIpbO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using VSCode given the tag you added to your post. With this information, I would suggest you look into the "Format on type" property in the settings of VSCode.
First, to enter the settings you do the following:

```
File > Preferences > Settings
```

Then you look up in the search bar "format on type" and you should see the next option available:

> Editor: Format on type 
>  ☐ Controls whether the editor should
> automatically format the line after typing.

It may be language dependent how well it works, and it could be affected by linting extensions. I hope it helped!

Extra information:

- [VS Code tips — Format on type](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-3Symq2-V8) - YT video
- [VSCode help for formatting code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help